# How to use CommandArgument in Ajax asp .net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Hi Guys I have a repeater that lists Menu items. I use command Argument to get Id of the per Item to use in code behind.Now I want to use Ajax to get Id of Item in repeater

My Repeater;

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repMasterMenu">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"  /></td>
            <td>
                <%#Eval("MenuName") %>
            </td>
            <td>
               <asp:ImageButton ID="Edit" runat="server"   ImageUrl="~/admin/img/duzenle_16x16.gif"  CommandArgument=<%#Eval("Id") %>   onclick="edit" Width="10px"  />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="Delete" ImageUrl="~/admin/img/sil_16x16.gif" runat="server" CommandArgument=<%#Eval("Id") %> onclick="del" width="10px"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

As You see I use Commandargument to get Id of items with ImageButton. as I said I want to use Ajax But How Can I get Id of a row wıth ImageButton
Edit:
I have done something like this to get Id but I always get firts item Id no matter which one i click

```
function Edit() {
     var ClickId = $('[id*="Edit"]')
         .click(function () {
             var nId = $(ClickId).data("id");
             alert(nId).val();
         })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind `ID` in data attribute of html as shown below.

`data-id=<%# Eval("Id") %>`

It render the HTML like

```
<input type="image" src="~/admin/img/duzenle_16x16.gif" id="Edit" name="Edit" 
data-id="5" class="btnEdit">
```

Now assign some class to the imagebutton and bind click handler by that class selector and call ajax by getting the data-id attribute

```
$(".btnEdit").on("click", function(){
    var nId = $(this).data("id")
    alert(nId);
})
```

Comment: Okay but when I call it by (#Edit) its not working because repeater makes it something like contentplaceholder1_Edit_0 so more content, Id changes. Also I need to get Id and text of it with Id and return it to a textbox

Comment: As i am not aware you are using master page. i am just giving you an idea of how you can get ID of item on client side.

Comment: Binding click handler is tricky, better to assign class and use it to bind click handler. i have updated answer.

Comment: Thank you m8 now I can get Id for each button but when i click 1 time it alerts like 4 times will it effect my webservice code ? will it try to make it for 4 times ?

Comment: It should not alert 4 times!

Comment: Yes it shouldnt but i click button it gives id on alert i click ok button it goes and then it alerts again